# Off-server merging in Git

Tags: git

We have a central git server for our projects. My friend and I are working on a single project after both cloning this project. Now we need to merge our code changes, but sadly our central server is not available currently.

I wonder is it possible that we merge our code changes locally, keeping all change histories, and then push all changes later when server is up? From locally, I mean transferring changes via a disk or using a temporary server on a local computer to merge changes.

If I didn't need history, I would just used diff/folder compare to transfer changes from one to another. But I like to transfer history too.

Comment: If you are somehow able to ```git fetch``` his branch, you can ```merge``` it into your local branch, which then contains all changes made **or** it complaints and lets you know where the ```merging conflicts``` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can :

- copy one's repo to the other's machine
- open an ssh access on one machine, and use this access to fetch & merge from the other machine

**copying the repo**

1. using some medium (a USB stick ? a .tar.gz through mail or scp ?) copy the `.git/` directory from one machine to the other
   say your own clone is located at `repo` (with its own `repo/.git/` directory), and that you copied your colleague's `.git/` directory to `fred/`, next to `repo/`
2. from `repo`, add a new remote :

   ```
   git remote add fred ../fred
   ```
3. `fred` is now a valid remote :

   ```
   git fetch fred
   git merge fred/master
   # or
   git rebase fred/master
   # etc ...
   ```
4. to pass back the data : apply similar actions to copy your updated repo to your colleague's station

**opening an ssh access**

*note :*

- the quick&dirty way is to connect on your colleague's station with his own user account,
- if you want to set up a cleaner, more stable solution, you should create an extra user account (`git` for example ...), create a bare repo on fred's station with this account, and have fred share its own repo by pushing to `git@localhost:...`

for the quick&dirty way :

1. start an ssh server on `fred`'s station

```
# on ubuntu :
sudo service ssh start
```

2. from your laptop : add `fred`'s repo as a remote through ssh

```
# obviously : use fred's station IP
git remote add fred fred@192.168.xx.xx:path/to/repo
```

3. run `git fetch fred` (ask fred to type his password once ...)
4. stop the ssh server on fred's station
5. merge your changes ...
6. you can even restart the ssh server on fred's station and use `git push` to send your local changes to fred

If you are actually targetting fred's working repo (which is prbably a non bare repo), `git` will refuse to update the branch currently checked out on his station.

Fred can checkout anything else than the updated branch -- `git checkout HEAD` for example, will temporarily put him in a detached head state, he can run `git checkout that/branch` after it has been updated.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you can practically can merge 2 git folders by setting one as remote for other one.